# kdiff3 unresponsive gui issue

Tags: unity, kde, qt

I've used kdiff3 a lot on standard ubuntu distribution. Sometime ago, I've found that it's interface became unresponsive: open file too long, applying changes tooks 2-3 seconds (pressing Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, or Ctrl+3) and etc. How can I found why it became slow? Is there any issues with kde programs on standard ubuntu unity interface or something?